# C# - EventLogSession.ExportLog method throws EventLogNotFoundException in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, event-log

I'm trying to implement a feature in a .NET Framework 4.7.2 WPF application which would allow customers to export their local application event log as part of a diagnostics package. I wrote this method:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Exports only errors from local application event log
/// </summary>
void addWindowsEventLog(String exportPath) {
    const String QUERY_ERRORS = "*[System/Level=2]";
    using (var eventLogSession = new EventLogSession()) {
        eventLogSession.ExportLog("Application", PathType.LogName, QUERY_ERRORS, exportPath);
    }
}
```

For some reason it's failing with this exception:

```
System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogNotFoundException
   at System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogException.Throw(Int32)
   at System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.NativeWrapper.EvtExportLog(System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogHandle, System.String, System.String, System.String, Int32)
```

Event log not found? I'm targetting the `Application` log, which clearly exists and I set `PathType` parameter to `LogName`. What gives?

- I've verified that I'm passing a fully-qualified file path for `exportPath` and that the directory exists.
- This application always runs in an administrative context, so it doesn't appear to be a rights issue.
- Interestingly, though, the issue isn't reproducible in a simple console application.

According to the stack trace, the exception is being thrown by [Win32 native function EvtExportLog](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/0502da710977fcee6cbd1137f5122c3ec42607a0/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.CoreCLR.Eventing/DotNetCode/Eventing/UnsafeNativeMethods.cs#L790-L800).

Comment: Not sure, but could wrapping it under ```try``` and ```catch``` block.

Comment: @Mike, I was able to reproduce that behavior but only if I execute the application in an elevated context too. Executing it without administrative context, your code works perfectly (on my machine). I have no clue yet why this is the case but probably it's a (temporary) solution for you too.

Comment: @MarkusSafar - Thanks! That's a good lead. Unfortunately, this app **needs** to run in an elevated context for other purposes.

I wonder if we found a bug?

Comment: Is your export path accessible to the adminstrative context? An example coming to mind is network drives, by default, the network drives of users are not made available to their administrative counterparts (run as admin, basically runs in a mirror session with admin rights). Mind trying to hardcode the destination? (something like C:\tmp\export.evt) just to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue isn't in the code, but in parameter values, specifically in `targetFilePath` parameter:

1. Ensure that destination directory path exist. This method doesn't create missing directories.
2. Ensure that destination file does not exist. This method cannot overwrite existing file.
3. Ensure that you are passing full path to a file. This method doesn't support relative paths and environment variables.

The `EventLogNotFoundException` isn't necessary related to first `path` parameter, it can be related to `targetFilePath` parameter too. And I suspect that this is the case.

Comment: Thanks, you were correct. The `exportPath` parameter contained a directory that didn't exist. The exception type name `EventLogNotFoundException` was extremely misleading.

Answer (score 0):

If the EventLogNotFoundException's Message is "The system cannot find the path specified", then make sure exportPath contains an existing path for the file

Comment: Please re-read the question. Your answer has NOTHING to do with the OP's question.

Comment: OP is getting an EventLogNotFoundException and i'm saying that OP has to look at the Exception's Message, because the exception can be thrown with different Messages.

Is OP getting the Exception with "The system cannot find the path specified" i don't know for sure but it's possible, you telling me it has nothing to do with OP's question is ridiculus.

Also, I can't reproduce what you're saying: that it isn't working when run with  administrive priveliges

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I somehow misinterpreted your answer, my apologies for that.

Answer (score 0):

try to wrapping your eventLogSession.ExportLog call in a try-catch block might provide more detailed error information that could help diagnose the issue.